# Is it possible to use LDAP authentification via `.htaccess` with MAMP?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, ldap, mamp

Is it possible to use LDAP authentification via `.htaccess` with MAMP?

I think I need to include/enable the Apache-Module but I'm not sure how to do it?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score -1):

Enalble it

```
a2enmod authnz_ldap
a2enmod ldap
/etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

In htaccess you use

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "secured site"
AuthBasicProvider ldap

AuthLDAPUrl "ldap://server/ou=People,dc=example,dc=local"
AuthLDAPBindDN "cn=reader,dc=example,dc=local"
AuthLDAPBindPassword the_secret_one
AuthzLDAPAuthoritative Off
Require valid-user
```